# how to pass pointer and got the result in function?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, c, function

please see code as follow :

```
- (BOOL)postAction :( NSString*) url  params:(NSDictionary*) params  bodySize:(NSNumber**)bodySize
{
... 
int size = 1999;

NSNumber* value =[[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:size];


bodySize =  &value;


 ...}
```

use the function  as follows:

```
NSNumber* size ;  
[self postAction:@"http://webserver/ss.php" params:params bodySize:&size];



// can not got the size value at all…


 int i = [size intValue]; 
//will throw nil exception !
```

my question is that how to correct this code above ?

many thanks for your help !

Regards

Comment: Can't you make it return the `NSNumber` object instead?

Comment: I don't know if you've seen it already, but if you are writing a method like this you really should look at the free ASIHttpRequest library (really pretty much a few classes) that lets you easily post data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want this:

```
//bodySize =  &value;
*bodySize = value;
```

Comment: Probably not; pass by reference is extremely rare properly written iOS apps.

Comment: @bbum That is incorrect. Throughout apple's own code `NSError`s are passed by reference, as well as some other instances with `NSScanner`.

Comment: Yes;  that would be the one rare, specific, use case...   When I said "rare" I meant "this pattern is extremely rare", not that, once decided upon, a particular pattern won't be used widely.   There are, what, a half dozen to a dozen *other* uses of pass by reference across the framework APIs?  (Thanks for the comment, it bore explanation, certainly).

Answer (score 4):

## If you are using pass-by-reference in iOS or Mac OS X, you are probably doing it wrong.

Seriously-- pass by reference is an exceedingly rare pattern to use.  It is pretty much entirely reserved to `(NSError**)` across the APIs.

Not to say that there isn't a reason to use pass-by-reference, but this isn't it.

Specifically, if you need to return an `NSNumber`, then return it!

```
- (NSNumber *) foo;
```

If that method returns `nil`, that is just as good as returning a `BOOL` `NO`.  And it sets you up to follow the very common pattern of using `NSError`:

```
- (NSNumber *) foo: (NSError **) error;
```

Answer (score 2):

Ideally, you should always check the pointer before dereferencing it:

```
If ( bodySize )
    *bodySize = value;
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the above two answers. To be more clear, NSNumber is an object (Unlike NSInteger or NSUInteger). So you should directly point your pointer to that object.